# Reorder a sorted array to rank-correlate another array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I need to simulate high-dimensional joint distribution using Iman-Conover method. Speed is crucial. One of the bottlenecks boils down to the following question: given a sorted array `x` and an unsorted array `y` of the same size, how to efficiently reorder `x` such that `x` and `y` are perfectly rank-correlated.

Straightforwardly, I did

```
template<typename indtype, typename valtype>
struct compare
{
  valtype *a;
  compare(valtype *a): a(a){}
  bool operator() (indtype i, indtype j) { return a[i] < a[j]; }
};


// `xReordered` stores the result.
// `recycle` is an auxiliary container storing indices.
template<typename indtype, typename valtype>
void reorder(valtype *x, indtype xsize, valtype *y, 
             valtype *xReordered, 
             std::vector<indtype> &recycle)
{
  recycle.resize(xsize);
  for(indtype i = 0; i < xsize; ++i) recycle[i] = i;
  std::sort(recycle.begin(), recycle.end(), 
    compare<indtype, valtype> (y));
  for(indtype i = 0; i < xsize; ++i) 
    xReordered[recycle[i]] = x[i];
}
```

Is there a faster way? I think the sorting is necessary and would probably dominate the overall time cost, but is it possible to do it without the auxiliary container `recycle`?

Thank you!

Edit: when memory is sufficient, copy `x` and pair it with `recycle`, and then sort. This is usually faster due to more efficient memory footprint during sorting.

Comment: I don't think there is a portable way to do it. You may be able to do it by wrapping the iterators of the container to sort and override std::iter_swap such that you swap the elements in x at the same time.